# What is the right away to update a panel using AJAX?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-ajax

In MVC4 applications, I would like to update a panel using AJAX but using jQuery methods instead using AjaxExtensions from MVC.

But my problem is the `updatePanelId`.

I've seen several people use this to update it when has success:

```
success: function (response) {
    var $target = $("#target");
    var $newHtml = response;
    $target.replaceWith($newHtml);
}
```

But when I do this, it forces me to use in every partial view that includes the `id="target"` at the root level of my razor view, and I guess that's not a good practice; I said this because I've realized when I use AjaxExtensions it doesn't happens, replace the update and it does not remove the `panelId`. But using jQuery it does.

Any idea to port the AjaxExtensions feature to jQuery?

Comment: @Cory Oh I didn't have idea about that function. So this is the method which would be similiar in AjaxExtensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use just:

```
$("#target").html(response); // it will just update content of the $("#target") container
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [jQuery's `.load` function](http://api.jquery.com/load/). This will load the contents of the URL you specify into the target element. You can optionally specify a selector after the URL in load to only grab part of the target page.

```
$(function() {
  $("#target").load("/MyURL");
});
```

[JavaScript same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) applies to this.